# MySQL query to consolidate table

Tags: mysql, sql, consolidation

Can you help me create a query that will convert the 1st table (left) to the 2nd table (right). I need to consolidate the product codes to the Purchase Order.

PO table:

[image]

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: can you give me dump of your table with few record,Then I can give you a complete query!

Comment: @MohamedNizar Here is my dump query.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9wbepkmm3s5hwpp/PO%20Table.sql?dl=0

Comment: @IshitaSinha I haven't tried any query yet.

Comment: Folow this two queries. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09408/2/4   , http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09408/1/0

Comment: I have updated a working query!

Comment: @majortsai did you find right answer?

Comment: @majortsai why don't you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
CONCAT(
  'count(case when PONumber = ''',
  PONumber,
  ''' then 1 end) AS ',
  replace(PONumber, ' ', '')
 )
) INTO @sql
 from PO;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT pt.ProductCode, ', @sql, ' from PO pt
group by ProductCode');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But this query does not did the result I needed.

Comment: I do expect some changes on it.If you can give example data will save time!

Answer (score 0):

In mysql there is lack o window functions which will be the best thing here.

But for your particular problem this will solve the issue.

```
SELECT 
    product_code,
    (SELECT count from your_table t2 
        Join t1 on t2.product_code = t1.product_code and t2.po_number = 'PO1') as PO1,
     (SELECT count from your_table t3
        Join t1 on t3.product_code = t1.product_code and t3.po_number = 'PO2') as PO2,
     (SELECT count from your_table t4
        Join t1 on t4.product_code = t1.product_code and t5.po_number = 'PO3') as PO3
From your_table t1
```

Just use your table name and column names. Unfortunately if you will add po4 you need to add it to the query. If you would use for example Postgres - you would not have this problem.